# How to convert latex algorithm2e into msword format

Tags: algorithms, conversion, algorithm2e, msword

I need to write below latex algorithm using windows words,
How I can do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\DontPrintSemicolon
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\KwIn{$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$}
\KwOut{$e$, $r$}
Calculate~$x$ and~$y$\;
\lIf{$k \geq n$}{$m_2$}\;
\lIf{$h \geq j$}{$m_1$}\;
\Else{%
\Repeat{$|a(i+1)-a(i)| < \epsilon$}{%
  Initialisation: $g(0) = nj$\;\label{stepA}
  $i=0$\;
  Compute~$n_2$
  \[
    n(i) = \frac{a}{b(i)\sqrt{3v}}
  \]
  \nl Update~$b$
  \[
    b(i+1) = (-\frac{1}{2(g(i)/D} + 1)
  \]
  \nl $i = i + 1$\;
  }
 }
 \caption{My algorithm}
\label{algo:b}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not using LaTeX and if you want to use MS work just copy-paste the pictures of it?

Comment: @RomainPicot it is not acceptable becasue the picture is not clear

Comment: I'm not a MSword user so would be difficult for me to help you for the conversion. But you know what I'll do. Cleared the result to paste it. Anyway someone else could have a better solution.

Comment: Maybe `tex4ht` could be configured to support algorhitm package, but don't expect to preserve exact formatting and appearance as in pdf